# How can I group element and list them all together in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have something like this:

```
time 0   1   2   3   4   5
Val1 32  12  56  45  3   67
Val2 60  34  2   5   13  90
```

I want a list of sub-array composed of 3 values like this:

```
dataset=   [
[["32", "12", "56"], ["45", "3", "67"]],
[["60", "34", "2"], ["5", "13", "90"]]
 ]
```

How can I do it? This line gives me only list of rows

```
df.values.tolist()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df=df.set_index('time')
df.groupby(np.arange(df.shape[1])//3,axis=1).agg(lambda x : x.values.tolist()).values.tolist()
[[[32, 12, 56], [45, 3, 67]], [[60, 34, 2], [5, 13, 90]]]
```

Comment: It gives me an error on 'Time'. May can it be that it is not an index?

Comment: @HugoB you can drop it df=df.drop('time',1)

Answer (score 0):

```
time 0   1   2   3   4   5 

Val1 32  12  56  45  3   67

Val2 60  34  2   5   13  90
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

data= [[0,32,60],[1,12,34],[2,56,2],[3,45,5],[4,3,13],[5,67,90]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["time","val1","val2"])
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert the whole DataFrame to list, followed by splitting each of those lists into 2 separate lists.

```
df2=df.values.tolist() #Convert the DataFrame to List
lst_split=[]
for lst in df2:
    temp1=lst[:len(lst)//2] #Create First Half of the split
    temp2=lst[len(lst)//2:] #Create Second Half of the split
    lst_split.append(temp1)
    lst_split.append(temp2) #Appending to the Final list
```

Comment: Adding some explanation can also help understand answer better.